# How to pass parameters to POST request using Retrofit and then serialize request?

Tags: android, kotlin, post, serialization, retrofit

I am switch from *iOS* to *Android* and try to implement a POST request using *Retrofit*, but don't understand my fault, please check my code, and will say where I did a mistake.

Through *Postman* all works well, body raw value: `{"players": ["player"], "action" : "add"}`

My code without data class below.

Interface

```
interface ApiRequests {
    @POST("/startup")
    fun getDataVenom(
        @Field("players") players: Array<String>,
        @Field("action") action: String
    ): Call<ObjectFromResponse>
}
```

Get data:

```
   private fun getCurrentData() {
        tv_textView.visibility = View.GONE
        tv_timeStamp.visibility = View.GONE
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val api2 = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL_VENOM)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ApiRequests::class.java)

     val players: Array<String> = arrayOf("players")

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val response = api2.getDataVenom(players = players, action = "add").awaitResponse()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                val data = response.body()!!
                Log.d(TAG, data.toString())

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    tv_textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    tv_timeStamp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }

            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Seems like something went wrong...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`@Body` annotation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Body.html):

> Use this annotation on a service method param when you want to directly control the request body of a POST/PUT request... The object will be serialized using the Retrofit instance Converter and the result will be set directly as the request body. Body parameters may not be null.

You might use

```
@POST("/startup")
fun getDataVenom(
    @Body body: BodyDTO
): Call<ObjectFromResponse>
```

where `BodyDTO` is

```
data class BodyDTO(
    @SerializedName("players") private val players: Array<String>,
    @SerializedName("action") private val action: String
)
```